# Define Custom Text with a Counter

Tags: counters

I would like to achieve this: Every time I write, say, `\mypair`, it should output, say, `#Pair 1`, then on the next use `#Pair 2`, etc.

(1) How do I do that?
(2) How do I add the option to reset or resume the counter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This defines commands `\resetmycounter`, `\resumemycounter`, and `\mypair`. When you use `\resetmycounter`, it remembers the value and starts over with a new counter. When you use `\resumemycounter` it forgets the current value and goes back to the previous value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycountnum}
\newcounter{mycount}

\newcommand\resetmycounter{
    \stepcounter{mycountnum}
    \ifcsname themycount\roman{mycountnum}\endcsname \else
        \newcounter{mycount\roman{mycountnum}}
    \fi
}
\newcommand\resumemycounter{\addtocounter{mycountnum}{-1}}
\newcommand\mypair{%
    \stepcounter{mycount\roman{mycountnum}}
    \#Pair \csname themycount\roman{mycountnum}\endcsname
}


\begin{document}
\mypair

\mypair
\mypair
\mypair

\mypair

Reset:

\resetmycounter

\mypair
\mypair
\mypair

Reset:

\resetmycounter
\mypair

Resume:
\resumemycounter
\mypair

Resume:
\resumemycounter

\mypair
\mypair

Reset:
\resetmycounter
\mypair
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you have guessed you need a counter. When you define a counter, say `\newcounter{Test}` there is also a command `\theTest` defined that will print the number. If you like you can redefine this to print it some other way, but without knowing a bit more of how it is supposed to be used, I would not recommend to put the `#Pair` here. Anyway you need to increment the counter before using it, which done using `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter`. So define a command that increments and prints the counter, like `\myTest` in the example below.

To reset the counter you can do `\setcounter{Test}{0}`, which is the manual form. You can also use the optional parameter to `\newcounter` to reset it with some other counter, e.g. `section`.

You can find more about counters on https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{Test}[section]
\newcommand\myTest{\stepcounter{Test}\#Pair \theTest}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\myTest\ \myTest
\setcounter{Test}{0}
\myTest\ \myTest

\section{New section}
\myTest\ \myTest\ \myTest

\end{document}
```

[image]