# Define a custom counter with optional textual postfix annotation useable in crossreferencing

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, counters, ref

**Question summery:**

How to change my implementation, that counter can print 1.1 , 1.2a, 1.2b , 1.3 where the number before the point is the section number an the part after the point is a own counter?

**Question in long:**
I would like to tweak my command for generating an "exercise counter".
First I show you, how I want to use my command, and then I am trying to describe the wanted behavior. At the end I show you my current impementation, which does not what I want:

```
\section{Bla}
\exerciseOpt[a]{test}\label{ex1}
[...]
After \ref{ex1} we can jump to \ref{ex2}  and [...]
\exerciseOpt[b]{test}\label{ex2}
[...]
\exerciseOpt{test}\label{ex3}
```

The "After"-line should printed like:

```
After 1.1a we can jump to 1.1b and [...]
```

While the command `\exerciseOpt` should print a "headline" bounded at section number and an own number and showing the optional parameter as textual postfix like:

```
Exercise 1.1a test
```

and on the second call

```
Exercise 1.1b test
```

while the third call should give

```
Exercise 1.2 test
```

I have found similar questions but their point are to different to my problem or didn't cover enought information for me:

- [Define Custom Text with a Counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341489/define-custom-text-with-a-counter)
- [\ref with custom text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582657/ref-with-custom-text)
- [Cross-Reference with custom text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70143/cross-reference-with-custom-text)
- [Getting a proper reference number with \ref while using custom counter and environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512715/getting-a-proper-reference-number-with-ref-while-using-custom-counter-and-envir)

And here is my command implementation, which doesn't handle the counter as I wanted:

```
\newcounter{excounter}[section]
\renewcommand{\theexcounter}{\thesection.\arabic{excounter}}
\newcommand{\showexcounter}{\theexcounter}
\newcommand{\exerciseOpt}[2][\relax]{%
     \def\myOptional{#1}
     \refstepcounter{excounter}
     \if\myOptional\relax
        \textbf{Exercise: \showexcounter : #2}%
     \else
        \textbf{Exercise: \showexcounter\myOptional : #2}%
     \fi
}
```

An **"working minimal code example"** which shows, that the numbers are not like I want to be in `\ref` output and directly in command `\exerciseOpt`, too

```
\documentclass{article}

    \newcounter{excounter}[section]
    \renewcommand{\theexcounter}{\thesection.\arabic{excounter}}
    \newcommand{\showexcounter}{\theexcounter}
    \newcommand{\exerciseOpt}[2][\relax]{%
         \def\myOptional{#1}
         \refstepcounter{excounter}
         \if\myOptional\relax
            \textbf{Exercise: \showexcounter : #2}%
         \else
            \textbf{Exercise: \showexcounter\myOptional : #2}%
         \fi
    }

\begin{document}

    \section{Bla}


    \noindent{}\exerciseOpt[a]{test number should be 1.1a}\label{ex1}
 
   \noindent{}After \ref{ex1} we can jump to \ref{ex2}  and [...]\newline
  \noindent{}it should be: After 1.1a we can jump to 1.1b and [...]

     \noindent{}\exerciseOpt[b]{test number should be 1.1b}\label{ex2}


     \noindent{}\exerciseOpt{test number should be 1.2}\label{ex3}
   
    \section{blub}
    \noindent{} \exerciseOpt{test number should be 2.1}\label{ex4}


\end{document}
```